# SQL equivalent when PIVOT is not available in SQL Server CE

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-ce

I have a problem with a SQL query that runs correctly except on Microsoft SQL Server CE (no PIVOT support). The query is the following:

```
SELECT 
    *, [1] as IMGN1, [2] as IMGN2, [3] as IMGN3,
    [4] as IMGN4, [5] as IMGN5, [6] as IMGN6,
    [7] as IMGN7, [8] as IMGN8, [9] as IMGN9, 
    [10] as IMGN10 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         area.CoilId as CID, area.DEFECTID,
         (SELECT SUM(s2.endposmd - s2.startposmd) 
          FROM sections s2 
          WHERE s2.OutCoilID = 999999 
            AND s2.InCoilId <= area.coilid) AS POSITIONMD, 
         d1.DNO as CAMERADEFECTNO, d1.IMAGE_NO as IMAGE_NO,
         area.MERGEDTO as MERGEDTO
     FROM 
         (OutCoils AS oc
     INNER JOIN 
         sections AS s ON oc.OutCoilId = s.OutCoilId
     INNER JOIN 
         defects AS area ON area.coilid = s.InCoilId  
                         AND area.PositionMD >= s.StartPosMD 
                         AND area.PositionMD <= s.EndPosMD
     INNER JOIN 
         defects AS d1 ON d1.CoilId = area.CoilId 
                       AND d1.MergedTo = area.DEFECTID)   
     WHERE 
         oc.OutCoilID = 999999 AND area.MergedTo = -2) AS SourceTable 
PIVOT
    (MIN([CAMERADEFECTNO]) FOR [IMAGE_NO]
          IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])
    ) AS PivotTable 
ORDER BY 
    PositionMD;
```

How can this be translated to a valid SQL query for non PIVOT editions?

I tried something using CASE but I have a problem with the subquery inside the aggregate function I use to get POSITIONMD, the rest is already working properly. Any idea of how to get POSITIONMD?

```
SELECT 
area.DEFECTID as DEFECTID, 
min(CASE when d1.MERGEDTO = area.DEFECTID then area.COILID end) CID,
min(CASE when d1.MERGEDTO = area.DEFECTID then area.MERGEDTO end) MERGEDTO,
min(CASE when d1.MERGEDTO = area.DEFECTID then (select sum(s2.endposmd - s2.startposmd) from sections s2 where s2.OutCoilID=999999 and s2.InCoilId<=area.coilid) end) POSITIONMD,
sum(CASE when d1.IMAGE_NO = 1 then (d1.DNO) end) IMGN1,
sum(CASE when d1.IMAGE_NO = 2 then (d1.DNO) end) IMGN2,
sum(CASE when d1.IMAGE_NO = 3 then (d1.DNO) end) IMGN3,
sum(CASE when d1.IMAGE_NO = 4 then (d1.DNO) end) IMGN4,
sum(CASE when d1.IMAGE_NO = 5 then (d1.DNO) end) IMGN5,
sum(CASE when d1.IMAGE_NO = 6 then (d1.DNO) end) IMGN6,
sum(CASE when d1.IMAGE_NO = 7 then (d1.DNO) end) IMGN7,
sum(CASE when d1.IMAGE_NO = 8 then (d1.DNO) end) IMGN8,
sum(CASE when d1.IMAGE_NO = 9 then (d1.DNO) end) IMGN9,
sum(CASE when d1.IMAGE_NO = 10 then (d1.DNO) end) IMGN10
FROM ( steinb.OutCoils AS oc
INNER JOIN steinb.sections AS s ON oc.OutCoilId=s.OutCoilId
INNER JOIN steinb.defects AS area ON area.coilid=s.InCoilId  AND area.PositionMD>=s.StartPosMD AND area.PositionMD<=s.EndPosMD
INNER JOIN steinb.defects AS d1 ON d1.CoilId=area.CoilId AND d1.MergedTo=area.DEFECTID AND d1.IMAGE_NO!=0)  
WHERE oc.OutCoilID=999999 GROUP BY area.DEFECTID ORDER BY PositionMD;
```

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Aren’t you able to simplify your question just handling one field? Or is it necessary that the answer do all the job for you?

Comment: @Jaime, you want the asker to give you *less* information?

Comment: @RussellFox, yes, that’s exactly what I am asking. The easier the question, the easier the answer. Do you think it’s necessary to include 10 case when? Is not enough with 2 for asking?

Comment: Rigth now, the only problem is on the CASE giving POSiTIONMD as output. How can the subquery inside be run to obtain the same? Thank you.

Comment: @Jaime, there is a way to professionally steer new contributors into asking better questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gotcha. I believe you just need to remove the MIN:

```
SELECT 
    DEFECTID = area.DEFECTID
    , CID = MIN(CASE when d1.MERGEDTO = area.DEFECTID then area.COILID end) 
    , MERGEDTO = MIN(CASE when d1.MERGEDTO = area.DEFECTID then area.MERGEDTO end) 
    , POSITIONMD = CASE when d1.MERGEDTO = area.DEFECTID then (select sum(s2.endposmd - s2.startposmd) from sections s2 where s2.OutCoilID=999999 and s2.InCoilId<=area.coilid) END
    , IMGN1 = sum(CASE when d1.IMAGE_NO = 1 then (d1.DNO) END)
    , IMGN2 = sum(CASE when d1.IMAGE_NO = 2 then (d1.DNO) end)
    , IMGN3 = sum(CASE when d1.IMAGE_NO = 3 then (d1.DNO) end)
    , IMGN4 = sum(CASE when d1.IMAGE_NO = 4 then (d1.DNO) end)
    , IMGN5 = sum(CASE when d1.IMAGE_NO = 5 then (d1.DNO) end)
    , IMGN6 = sum(CASE when d1.IMAGE_NO = 6 then (d1.DNO) end)
    , IMGN7 = sum(CASE when d1.IMAGE_NO = 7 then (d1.DNO) end)
    , IMGN8 = sum(CASE when d1.IMAGE_NO = 8 then (d1.DNO) end)
    , IMGN9 = sum(CASE when d1.IMAGE_NO = 9 then (d1.DNO) end)
    , IMGN10 = sum(CASE when d1.IMAGE_NO = 10 then (d1.DNO) end)
FROM ( steinb.OutCoils AS oc
    INNER JOIN steinb.sections AS s ON oc.OutCoilId=s.OutCoilId
    INNER JOIN steinb.defects AS area ON area.coilid=s.InCoilId  AND area.PositionMD>=s.StartPosMD AND area.PositionMD<=s.EndPosMD
    INNER JOIN steinb.defects AS d1 ON d1.CoilId=area.CoilId AND d1.MergedTo=area.DEFECTID AND d1.IMAGE_NO!=0)  
WHERE oc.OutCoilID=999999 GROUP BY area.DEFECTID ORDER BY PositionMD;
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. The main issue I have with the CASE implementation is the sub-query that I have to run inside the MIN() to obtain POSITIONMD. The rest of the query is already working well. What can I do to obtain POSITIONMD?

Comment: “Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.” This is the error I get.

Comment: The problem is that removing the MIN I got a different error because I am using GROUP BY at the end and I am not telling how to treat de different POSITIONMD values. This is why i use MIN also for CID and MERGEDTO.  Any other option for that query inside MIN? Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble figuring out what your data looks like, particularly with those joins with "<=" and ">=" instead of just "=". Are there multiple [defects] per OutCoils? Do you just want the most recent?

Comment: It was finally solved removing the MIN() and adding on the GROUP BY clause some of the fields used by the subquery to obtain POSITIONMD. Thank you for your time and effort.